# byte position: file_get_contents vs fopen

Tags: php, file, media, fopen, fseek

I need some data from a specific byte in range in a binary file.
(concatenated jpegs, don't ask...)

So I have a `offset` and `length` data from an external API.
(I would guess that those are byte positions)

What works is the following:

```
$fileData = file_get_contents($binaryFile);
$imageData = substr($fileData, $offset, $length);
```

But i would rather not load the full file into memory and therefor tried `fopen`:

```
$handle = fopen($binaryFile, 'rb');
fseek($handle, $offset);
$imageData = fgets($handle, $length);
```

But that doesn't work. The data chunk is no valid image data.
So i assume i got the position wrong with `fopen`.

Any ideas on how the positions differ in `substr` vs `fopen`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote

> The data chunk is no valid image data

"image data" - but in your code you call `fgets()` to read that data. That's wrong, as image is binary data, not a text file, so you don't want it read it by lines ([docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)):

> fgets — Gets **line** from file pointer

This means `fgets()` would stop reading from file once it finds what it considers line end marker, which usually means stopping earlier and reading less than `$length` as there's pretty low chance such byte is not in the binary sequence.

So `fgets()` wrong method to use and this is the main issue. Instead you should pick less smart `fread()` (which does not know about lines and stuff, and just reads what you told). Finally you should `fclose()` the handle when you done. And naturally you should always check for errors, starting from `fopen()`:

```
if ($handle = fopen($binaryFile, 'rb')) {
    if (fseek($handle, $offset) === 0) {
       $imageData = fread($handle, $length);
       if ($imageData === false) {
          // error handling - failed to read the data
       }
    } else {
        // error handling - seek failed
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
   // error handling - can't open file
}
```

So always use right tool for the task, and if you are unsure what given method/function does, there's always [not-that-bad documentation](https://secure.php.net/docs.php) to peek.

Comment: thank you! :) i was pretty sure about fgets being the right tool #rtfm ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file_get_contents`, too. See this simple line:

```
imageData = file_get_contents($binaryFile, null, null, 0, $length);
```

And here the documentation of [file_get_contents](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php).